# Как заставить массив сохранить объект в Objective-C? РЕШЕНО

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone

Спасибо [[@ruman](/users/13585/ruman)](/users/13585/ruman) за намек места ошибки. Ссылки на объекты класса NSString в AIPost были слабыми. Исправил на сильные и все заработало.

Метод ("-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString* )elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString* )qName") выполняется несколько(в моем случае 100 раз). В конце метода я добавляю объект post в массив postStore. Но при завершении метода все значения переменных объекта post становятся nil, но сам объект сохраняется. Как "заставить" postStore сохранять не только сам объект, но и его переменные?
currentpubDate, currentDescription, currentTitle не nil'овые, дебажил, смотрел.
Ах, да. В итоге остается только последний пост.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"\tI found a %@ element", elementName);
    currentItem = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        currentGuid = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentpubDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentDescription = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
    if ([currentItem isEqualToString:@"guid"])
    {
        [currentGuid appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([currentItem isEqualToString:@"link"])
    {
        [currentLink appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([currentItem isEqualToString:@"title"])
    {
        [currentTitle appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([currentItem isEqualToString:@"pubDate"])
    {
        [currentpubDate appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([currentItem isEqualToString:@"description"])
    {
        [currentDescription appendString:string];
    }

}

 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    NSLog(@"ended element %@", elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        AIpost *post = [[AIPost alloc] init];
        post.postDate = currentpubDate;
        post.postText = currentDescription;
        post.postNumber = currentTitle;
        [postStore addObject:post];
    NSLog(@"added story: %@",currentTitle);
    } }
```

Comment: Откуда вы берете переменные currentpubDate, currentDescription, currentTitle.
Покажите где вы их объявляете и где присваиваете им значения.

Comment: Исправил в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
AIpost *post = [[AIPost alloc] init];
post.postDate = [currentpubDate copy];
post.postText = [currentDescription copy];
post.postNumber = [currentTitle copy];
[postStore addObject:post];
```

Comment: @ruman неа. Не поможет. Дело не в этом. postStore добавляет в себя объект post, в котором, кстати, все переменные postDate, postText, postNumber не nil, после выхода из метода post в postStore остается, но уже с nil'овыми переменными.

Comment: Интерфейс класса AIpost покажите.

Comment: Аааааа. Ссылки были слабыми. Исправил на сильные и все заработало. Спасибо большое!

Comment: =) Не забудьте опубликовать правильный ответ от себя.

Comment: Рейтинг пока не позволяет. Правил сам вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы сохраняете переменную вы сохраняете ссылку на область памяти. Таким образом, в вашем коде currentpubDate, currentDescription, currentTitle являются глобальными переменными инстанса. И скорее всего после выполнения функции `-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {` вы, потом эти переменные затираете.

Comment: currentpubDate, currentDescription, currentTitle глобальные объекты класса NSString во ViewController. Они не затираются. Затирается объект post, точнее все значения его переменных). Пробовал сделать post глобальным. Но теперь остается не только последний пост, а все становятся как последний.